# Next JS middleware with app directory, redirect on login and logout

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware

Hello next js developers,

I am new to the Next JS and I am trying to make a middleware for the redirection. If user is logged in then redirect to "/" also if he tries to open the login page and if he is logged out and try to open any page except "/login" and "/signup" then redirect it to "/login"

My code

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export const config = {
   matcher: "/",
};

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {

const token = req.cookies.get('token')?.value;

const isTokenExpired = (token: string) => {
    try {
        const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token);
        if (!decodedToken) return true; // Token is not valid
        return Date.now() >= decodedToken.exp * 1000;
    } catch (error) {
        return true;
    }
};

const url = req.nextUrl.clone()
if (token && isTokenExpired(token)) {
    Cookies.remove('token')
    console.log("Token expired, redirecting to login");
    url.pathname = "/login";
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
} else {
    console.log("Token valid, redirecting to home");
    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

}

Comment: have the same issue i want to check users state using context API and redirect to login page if user is not logged in and visit page